# How to run node.js app with nginx ssl in Jenkins in aws free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, certbot

I install nginx in EC2 instance but aws donot allow to install certificate in servers. I want to know how these steps are possible in deploying to aws free tier. And how to make this app live. Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have full control over what you install on the EC2 instance, therefore installing a custom TLS certificate is possible. What specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any reason, why you can't use Let's Encrypt (or any other certificate) in an EC2 box in free tier. However, you do need to have your own domain.